# Using $\;\left|1-\frac{\sin(x)}x\right|<\frac{x^2}2\,$ prove that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$

Tags: limits

So I’m not sure how to do this problem, I almost understand the squeeze theorem, but I have no idea how to prove it using the provided equation!

I would be extremely thankfull if you could help me:)

Using $\;\left|1-\dfrac{\sin(x)}x\right|<\dfrac{x^2}2\,$ prove that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}x=1\,.$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The squeeze theorem isn't entirely necessary here. You could just do a direct $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.

Comment: Hint: fixing $\epsilon>0$, what happens if $|x|<\delta$ with $\delta:=\sqrt{2\epsilon}$?

Comment: @J.G. why giving advice to root square epsilons, $|x|<1\implies x^2<|x|$ and we can deal with normal epsilons. When $x\to 0$ any polynomial in $x$ can be reduced to $|p(x)|< c|x|$ (c=sum of abs coeffs) with the same idea that $|x^n|<|x|$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @zwim Fair point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the squeeze theorem:

$$ 0 \leq |1-\sin(x)/x| \leq x^2/2$$

If we let $x \rightarrow 0 $ then the RHS tends to $0$ and so the squeeze theorem states that $|1-\sin(x)/x| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, meaning that $\sin(x)/x \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i dont know what "RHS" means.
Is there any way you could dumb the whole equation down for me?

Comment: Absolutely, RHS means "right hand side". Look at $|1-\sin(x)/x|$ in the first expression which you've also been given in the problem. Since it's in absolute values, it's certainly positive, so it's bounded below by $0$. We also know from the problem that the middle expression is less than $x^2/2$. So if we let $x\rightarrow 0$, the $|1-\sin(x)/x|$ is squeezed between $0$, so it has to be $0$ according to the squeeze theorem. But that can only be true if $1=\sin(x)/x$ for when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time! You're very helpfull:)

Comment: @AntanasStrumskis No worries! Good luck on your studies :)